# How do unary operators get parsed using RPN?

Tags: math, postfix-notation, unary-operator, rpn

Given the infix expression `-190 + 20`, what would the correct result look like as RPN?

`-190 + 20 == -190 20 +` ?

or..

`-190 + 20 == 190 - 20 +` ?

Are the rules for unary operators (negative) the same as other operators, but just a `right` associative property, and higher priority?

Similarly an expression like:
`-(9 + 9)`

Would be?
`-(9 + 9) = 9 - 9 +`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a typical RPN language, you can't have the same token `-` interpreted as either a unary or binary operator depending on context, because there is no context.  It has to always be one or the other. So commonly `-` is kept as the binary subtraction operator, and some other token is used for the unary negation operator.  Forth, for instance, called it `NEGATE`.  Thus in Forth, your `-190 + 20` could be coded as `190 NEGATE 20 +`, and your `-(9+9)` as `9 9 + NEGATE`.

Forth could also parse negative numbers, so your `-190 + 20` could also be coded `-190 20 +`.  However the `-` is not an operator in this instance, but merely part of the single token `-190`.  The only operator being used in this example is `+`.

If you write `190 - 20 +` in a typical RPN language, you will get a stack underflow (or else whatever happened to be on the stack, minus 190, plus 20) since `-` is unconditionally interpreted as the binary operator.

RPN has no concept of precedence nor associativity - those serve to resolve ambiguity in the evaluation of expressions, and RPN has no such ambiguity in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. What I mean is, during the shunting of infix to postfix, when the lexer identifies a token as a unary minus — (I've seen it suggested that) the unary minus should be set as right assoc, and have the highest precedence (i.e. is pow operator is 3, unary minus should be 4)?

Comment: Perfect answer from Eldredge. [Here](http://www.7th-stone.com/index.php?id=14) is a _Forth_ -like interpreter to play with.

Answer (score 0):

unary minus should be no issue.  If the stack has only a single operand after meeting a minus then it is unary.  One online RPN generator generates a gratis 0, so -b becomes 0-b.  But surely

```
    (-2)*(-3-5) should just be 2-3-5-*. 
    and
    -190 + 20 ==> 190-20+
    -(9 + 9) ==> 9 9 + -
    while
    (-a)*((-b)-(-c)) ==> a- b- c- -* (that one may need checking!!!)
```